# What are the formulae for quantifying the back radiation from greenhouse gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science

I am trying to find the formulae for quantifying the back radiation from greenhouse gases including CO2 and CH4 for the purposes of designing useful products such as more efficient double glazing units etc. I cannot find any properly conducted laboratory experiments on this, only school type demonstrations with plastic bottles and heat lamps. We want the specific formulae and the details of the experiments which confirm them so we can test our new inventions.

Comment: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com.   is more the place for this question, IMO

Comment: Yes, although I think this question fits this forum, you'd probably get a better one from Earth Sciences. I don't know off the top of my head, but could tell you how I'd go about it from cross sections and radiation patterns;   I'd probably confuse myself (let alone you) before I'd worked it all out and you want a fully packaged, clear, fully documented version. Only people who work with this stuff every day can give you that - I think most people here would derive it for themselves from first principles like me. Ping me if you can't find a better answer and I'll hazard one, at least in chat.

Comment: I can look up Cp,Cv, and calculate K, R (or look them up) for gases in the old text books I have, plenty of temperature related graphs too. However when  we learned about the greenhouse gas effect we presumed this must be an additional physical property of certain gases not previously known or taken account of in the heat related parameters which are to do with conduction. The greenhouse effect bit being an extra thermal effect which varies with the exact wavelength of I.R. radiation. How do we calculate the extra thermal effect of back radiation on top of the conduction bit Cv,Cp,K,R, etc ?